# ACM Paper Submission containing Chinese characters does not allow xeCJK package and does not support XeTeX Compiler

Tags: compiling, overleaf, cjk, acm, xecjk

Using the ACM Template - acmsmall version 2.1 (latest version at the moment of writing), the ACM upload system does not support XeTeX compiler; only LaTeX compiler is supported.

Here are my codes (minimal version):

```
\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand\BibTeX{{%
    Bib\TeX}}}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK TC}

\definecolor{eclipseStrings}{RGB}{42,0.0,255}
\definecolor{eclipseKeywords}{RGB}{127,0,85}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black}

% code listing
\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}   % <-- defined new list
\setlist[tabitem]{nosep,        % <-- new list setup
                  leftmargin=*,
                  label=$\bullet$,
                  after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},
                  }
\usepackage{booktabs}

% text box
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbset{%any default parameters
  width=0.95\textwidth,
  halign=justify,
  center,
  breakable,
  colback=white    
}

%%
%% end of the preamble, start of the body of the document source.
\begin{document}

\title{My Title here}

\begin{abstract}
My Abstract here 
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
This is Chinese content 我

\begin{tcolorbox}
  Chinese content in a box 我
\end{tcolorbox}

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{sample-base}

\end{document}
```

Here are part of the errors, as reported by ACM Submission Platform:

```
Below LaTeX Error detected:
! Critical Package xeCJK Error: The xeCJK package requires XeTeX to function. (xeCJK) (xeCJK) You must change your typesetting engine to (xeCJK) "xelatex" (xeCJK) instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex" or (xeCJK) "lualatex". (xeCJK) Loading xeCJK will abort! Type to continue. ... l.43 ..._critical:nn { xeCJK } { Require-XeTeX } }
! Undefined control sequence. \setCJKmainfont l.112 \setCJKmainfont
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type H for immediate help. ... l.112 \setCJKmainfont{N
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character 我 (U+6211) not set up for use with LaTeX. See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type H for immediate help. ... l.299 \item 我
```

I tried to change the codes and the compiler to LaTeX (in Overleaf), here are the modified codes:

```
\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand\BibTeX{{%
    Bib\TeX}}}

\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\definecolor{eclipseStrings}{RGB}{42,0.0,255}
\definecolor{eclipseKeywords}{RGB}{127,0,85}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black}

% code listing
\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}   % <-- defined new list
\setlist[tabitem]{nosep,        % <-- new list setup
                  leftmargin=*,
                  label=$\bullet$,
                  after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},
                  }
\usepackage{booktabs}

% text box
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbset{%any default parameters
  width=0.95\textwidth,
  halign=justify,
  center,
  breakable,
  colback=white    
}

%%
%% end of the preamble, start of the body of the document source.
\begin{document}

\title{My Title here}

\begin{abstract}
My Abstract here 
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
This is Chinese content 我

\begin{tcolorbox}
  Chinese content in a box 我
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{CJK}

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{sample-base}

\end{document}
```

which Overleaf returns an **empty PDF** without errors, but some warnings:

```
Package cmap Warning: pdftex in DVI mode - exiting.
Package hyperxmp Warning: Suppressing the _entire_ PDF Info dictionary. Please notify the hyperxmp maintainer.
Package caption Warning: The option `hypcap=true' will be ignored for this particular \caption on input line 667. See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

What should I do to make it error-free when uploading to ACM (or compile using LaTeX?)

Comment: Does the ACM site support LuaLaTeX, or only pdfLaTeX?

Comment: In any case, it appears that ACM doesn't accept the `xeCJK` or `CJKutf8` packages. Instead, [ACM appears to only accept the `CJK` package](https://authors.acm.org/proceedings/production-information/accepted-latex-packages). Could you try getting your document to compile using that package instead?

Comment: @bonk Yes I know ACM supported CJK package only. I tried it and found that the LaTeX codes don't even compile. Lots of *Undefined control sequence.* errors appeared. On the other hand, if using `\usepackage[encapsulated]{CJK}`, the same warning listed above appears and no PDF is generated as well.

Comment: do not use latex on overleaf, latex produces dvi, use pdflatex. (And warnings are not errors!)

Comment: wait. it's ACM that requires latex. `pdflatex` or `xelatex` works fine in Overleaf, but not accepted by ACM.

Comment: Hm, their web page is rather silent about compilation options, but their template contains png and pdf images and so it would be very curious if they wouldn't use at least pdflatex. Contact their support and ask.

Comment: If I compile with `pdflatex` (not `latex`) there is no problem whatsoever.

Comment: Yes @egreg but ACM only accepts `latex` compiler.

Comment: @Raptor I doubt it: `pdflatex` is quite certainly supported; I'd say it's the engine of choice, actually, because the `acmart` class loads `hyperxmp` which is essentially useless with the `latex` engine. They ask for LaTeX as opposed to LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, but the output is expected to be PDF anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The production team is switching to LuaLaTeX to accommodate tagging.  XeTeX is, AFAIK, not in the plans.

In the worst case scenario if your work contains just a handful of Chinese characters, you can typeset them separately and insert as images. This sucks, but this is going to work...