# Class acmart Error: No country present for an affiliation

Tags: acm, acmart

I encountered a weird bug in `latex` or `pdflatex` compiler using ACM Template (version 2.1).

Here are the codes:

```
%%
%% This is file `sample-acmsmall.tex',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}

%%
%% \BibTeX command to typeset BibTeX logo in the docs
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand\BibTeX{{%
    Bib\TeX}}}



\usepackage{CJKutf8}


% code listing
\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}   % <-- defined new list
\setlist[tabitem]{nosep,        % <-- new list setup
                  leftmargin=*,
                  label=$\bullet$,
                  after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},
                  }
\usepackage{booktabs}

% text box
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbset{%any default parameters
  width=0.95\textwidth,
  halign=justify,
  center,
  breakable,
  colback=white    
}

%%
%% end of the preamble, start of the body of the document source.
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}

%%
%% The "title" command has an optional parameter,
%% allowing the author to define a "short title" to be used in page headers.
\title{My Paper Title}

%%
%% The "author" command and its associated commands are used to define
%% the authors and their affiliations.
%% Of note is the shared affiliation of the first two authors, and the
%% "authornote" and "authornotemark" commands
%% used to denote shared contribution to the research.
\author{Author 1}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{My University}
  \streetaddress{My Street}
  \city{Hong Kong}
  \country{China}}
\email{author1@email.com}

\author{Author 2}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{My University}
  \streetaddress{My Street}
  \city{Hong Kong}
  \country{China}}
\email{author2@email.com}

\author{Author 3}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{My University}
  \streetaddress{My Street}
  \city{Hong Kong}
  \country{China}}
\email{author3@email.com}

\author{Author 4}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{My University}
  \streetaddress{My Street}
  \city{Hong Kong}
  \country{China}}
\email{author4@email.com}
\orcid{1234-5678-9012-3456}

%%
%% By default, the full list of authors will be used in the page
%% headers. Often, this list is too long, and will overlap
%% other information printed in the page headers. This command allows
%% the author to define a more concise list
%% of authors' names for this purpose.
\renewcommand{\shortauthors}{Authors et al.}

%%
%% The abstract is a short summary of the work to be presented in the
%% article.
\begin{abstract}
  Abstract here
\end{abstract}

%%
%% This command processes the author and affiliation and title
%% information and builds the first part of the formatted document.
\maketitle


%%
%% The next two lines define the bibliography style to be used, and
%% the bibliography file.
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{sample-base}

\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `sample-acmsmall.tex'.
```

It results in the error in the title:

> Class acmart Error: No country present for an affiliation.

However, as you can see from the codes above, all authors have marked their country. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/706196/270231

Comment: the class doesn't like that there is a group around the list of authors. it errors with a simply \begingroup/\endgroup too. It looks like a bug to me, but I can't look now.

Comment: put `\makeatletter \gdef\@ACM@checkaffil{} \makeatother` after \maketitle.

Comment: Magically it works! Please put it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class doesn't expect an environment or some other grouping around the author  and maketitle commands. It resets in `\maketitle` the checking command to empty, but only locally and so at the end of the group this is reset and leads to an error.

Add `\makeatletter \gdef\@ACM@checkaffil{} \makeatother` after `\maketitle`.

Answer (score 0):

The `acmart` document class appears to be incompatible with the `CJKutf8` package. Indeed, the ACM's [list of accepted packages](https://authors.acm.org/proceedings/production-information/accepted-latex-packages) includes `CJK` but *not* `CJKutf8`. Commenting out the `CJK*` environment in your template code resolves your error.

Comment: but the support of ACM asked me to use this package to resolve Chinese display issues.

Comment: Regarding what ACM support told you, did they recommend that you specifically use `CJKutf8` and not `CJK`? If they did recommend `CJKutf8`, then perhaps a follow-up with them is warranted, because the package doesn't seem to be *entirely* compatible with their document class. I haven't looked into the class's source code, so I don't know *exactly* why that is.

Comment: After testing your template code for a bit, it seems that `CJKutf8` is conflicting with the author affiliations. If you comment out the last author's `\affiliation` but keep the `CJK*` environment, the code compiles. If you keep all of the `\affiliation`s but comment out the `CJK*` environment, the code compiles. Perhaps there's a bug in `\affiliation` and/or `\country` that causes a conflict with `CJKutf8`?